# Laravel controller define with mask

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I have PagesController defined in my routes file:

```
Route::controller('/', 'PagesController');
```

But i use some more routes like:

```
Route::get('/admin', function()
{
....some code here
});
```

My second route doesn't work, because all other routes try to find functions in PagesController. I can change my controller to:

```
Route::controller('pages', 'PagesController');
```

But then in my home page, all links will be like www.test.com/pages/..., but i don't need that 'pages' in there. How to define my controller with mask or something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the order of your route definition to this:

```
Route::get('/admin', function()
{
....some code here
});

Route::controller('/', 'PagesController');
```

It will now look for `/admin` first, and if it cant find it, it when they go to your other routes...

Comment: I try this at first, but I had one mistake with my other routes. I try it one more time, and it works. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

Laravel allows you to easily define a single route to handle every action in a controller using simple, REST naming conventions. First, define the route using the Route::controller method:

```
Route::controller('pages', 'PagesController')
```

This is a single route to define all actions in a controller using REST naming conventions therefore you get the /pages.

For the root of your app you need to specify the method that you want to call within your PagesController.

Example:

```
Route::get('/', array('as' => 'home', 'uses' => 'PagesController@getIndex'));
```

Place this line at the top of your routes in the routes file.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `Route::controller({same content as the question})` to `Route::resource({same content as the question})`

Comment: This put an error with - method index does not exsist.